# Sum data from multiple csv files using pandas

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas

I have -many- csv files with the same number of columns (different number of rows) in the following pattern:

Files 1:

```
A1,B1,C1
A2,B2,C2
A3,B3,C3
A4,B4,C4
```

File 2:

```
*A1*,*B1*,*C1*
*A2*,*B2*,*C2*
*A3*,*B3*,*C3*
```

File ...

Output:

```
A1+*A1*+...,B1+*B1*+...,C1+*C1*+...
A2+*A2*+...,B2+*B2*+...,C2+*C2*+...
A3+*A3*+...,B3+*B3*+...,C3+*C3*+...
A4+...     ,B4+...     ,C4+...
```

For example:

Files 1:

```
1,0,0
1,0,1
1,0,0
0,1,0
```

Files 2:

```
1,1,0
1,1,1
0,1,0
```

Output:

```
2,1,0
2,1,2
1,1,0
0,1,0
```

I am trying to use python.pandas and was thinking of something like this to create the reading variables:

```
dic={}
for i in range(14253,14352):
        try:
                dic['df_{0}'.format(i)]=pandas.read_csv('output_'+str(i)+'.csv')
        except:
                pass
```

and then to sum the columns:

```
for residue in residues:
       for number in range(14254,14255):
               df=dic['df_14253'][residue]
               df+=dic['df_'+str(number)][residue]
```

residues is a list of strings which are the column names.

I have the problem that my files have different numbers of rows and are only summed up until the last row of df1. How could I add them up until the last row of the longest file - so that no data is lost? I think groupby.sum by panda could be an option but I don't understand how to use it.

To add an example - now I get this:

Files 1:

```
1,0,0
1,0,1
1,0,0
0,1,0
```

Files 2:

```
1,1,0
1,1,1
0,1,0
```

File 3:

```
1,0,0
0,0,1
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,0,1
```

File ...:

Output:

```
3,1,0
2,1,3
2,1,0
1,1,0
1,0,0
1,0,1
```

Comment: _I have the problem that my files have different numbers of rows and are only summed up until the last row of df1_.   

What would you do with remaining numbers ?

Comment: I have added an example to explain better what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Panel in pandas , a `3D`object, collection of dataframes :

```
dfs={ i : pd.DataFrame.from_csv('file'+str(i)+'.csv',sep=',',\
header=None,index_col=None) for i in range(n)} # n files.
panel=pd.Panel(dfs)
dfs_sum=panel.sum(axis=0)
```

`dfs` is a dictionnary of dataframes. Panel  completes automatically lacking values with Nan and does the good sum.  For example :

```
n [500]: panel[1]
Out[500]: 
     0   1   2
0    1   0   0
1    1   0   1
2    1   0   0
3    0   1   0
4  NaN NaN NaN
5  NaN NaN NaN
6  NaN NaN NaN
7  NaN NaN NaN
8  NaN NaN NaN
9  NaN NaN NaN
10 NaN NaN NaN
11 NaN NaN NaN

In [501]: panel[2]
Out[501]: 
     0   1   2
0    1   0   0
1    1   0   1
2    1   0   0
3    0   1   0
4    1   0   0
5    1   0   1
6    1   0   0
7    0   1   0
8  NaN NaN NaN
9  NaN NaN NaN
10 NaN NaN NaN
11 NaN NaN NaN

In [502]: panel[3]
Out[502]: 
    0  1  2
0   1  0  0
1   1  0  1
2   1  0  0
3   0  1  0
4   1  0  0
5   1  0  1
6   1  0  0
7   0  1  0
8   1  0  0
9   1  0  1
10  1  0  0
11  0  1  0

In [503]: panel.sum(0)
Out[503]: 
    0  1  2
0   3  0  0
1   3  0  3
2   3  0  0
3   0  3  0
4   2  0  0
5   2  0  2
6   2  0  0
7   0  2  0
8   1  0  0
9   1  0  1
10  1  0  0
11  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for this exact same thing, I find out that Panel is now Deprecated so I post here the news :

```
class pandas.Panel(data=None, items=None, major_axis=None, minor_axis=None, copy=False, dtype=None)
```

> Deprecated since version 0.20.0: The recommended way to represent 3-D data are with a >MultiIndex on a DataFrame via the to_frame() method or with the xarray package. >Pandas provides a to_xarray() method to automate this conversion.

```
to_frame(filter_observations=True)
```

> Transform wide format into long (stacked) format as DataFrame whose columns are >the Panel’s items and whose index is a MultiIndex formed of the Panel’s major and >minor

I would recommend using 
pandas.DataFrame.sum

```
DataFrame.sum(axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None, min_count=0, **kwargs)
```

> Parameters:
>   axis : {index (0), columns (1)}
>      Axis for the function to be applied on.

One can use it the same way as in B.M. answer